# Source for prohibition to listen to music during the 3 weeks

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, music, nine-days, three-weeks

What is the earliest source for the prohibition to listen to music during the 3 weeks?

Is there any dispute as to the timeframe of the prohibition (only 9 days, week of etc.)?

Comment: Note that the Shulchan Aruch forbids any music, any time. So obviously he doesn't mention that it's forbidden during the Three Weeks.

Answer (score 2):

I found this:

http://shulchanaruchharav.com/The%20Three%20Weeks/default.aspx?_ftnref1

The sources seem to be Mishna Brura: תקנא/טז and Magen Avrohom תקנא\י

Kitzur Shulhan Aruch says that it is permissible for someone whose profession is musical instruments to play in a Goy's house, that implies I guess that it's prohibited otherwise.

You're right, it's a difficult question. Everyone knows it's forbidden, but it's difficult to find sources.

Comment: It seems to be a minhag that developed during the time between the rishonim and the shulchan aruch as there is no mention of it or any other mourning customs in the Mishnah Torah which supposedly contains all obligatory halachot and minhagim which existed at the time it was written.